# fonts in Chrome not showing

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am having a little issue with a font in Chrome. I think it's the way I'm specifying it. I have:

```
font-family: "Myriad Pro", Tahoma, Arial;
```

That works well in FF, IE and Safari, but Chrome just shows me weird symbols.

Using font-family: Tahoma, Arial; works well for all the browsers, including Chrome. But I need Myriad Pro at least for IE, FF and Safari, how can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me with FF4.0.1. and Chrome 11 on Win7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on a mac? I found this: http://www.mactalk.com.au/56/83001-font-issue-google-chrome.html

Comment: I guess it's my Chrome build like they say there.

Answer (score 1):

Myriad Pro is NOT a web font. Because of this, Myriad Pro is not available in all browsers (also, not all computers have the font installed), you are going to end up with a lot of visitors who will only see Tahoma.

Try using @font-face. I recommend FontSquirrel's @font-face Generator. All you have to do is upload your font, then it generates the files and CSS you need to get a pretty consistent looking font in nearly all browsers, even IE6!

Answer (score 1):

Remove Myriad font from stack in css. Refresh your page. Then add this font back to your stack again and refresh your page. I don't know why, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Myriad Pro", Tahoma, Arial;
```

should it not be

```
"Myriad Pro", Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 0):

This also might be case of the browser for some reason not being able to access the Font. Happened before for me on Opera, it would only be able to access a few fonts, but none of the special fonts I tested that other browser could see just fine. Updates \ reinstall never resolved it for me, but after upgradin from Vista to 7 the problem went away.